# Нужна помощь по настройке отображения в строку

Tags: битрикс

Нужна помощь по настройке отображения в строку.

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<?foreach($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem):?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 mb20 mb50-md">
<div class="h4"><a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>"><?=$arItem["NAME"]?></a></div>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"]!="N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])):?>
<a href="<?=$arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"]?>" class="float-md-left mr30-md w140-md mb20 d-block" rel="nofollow"><img class="full-max" src="<?=$arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"]?>" alt="<?=$arItem["NAME"]?>" title="<?=$arItem["NAME"]?>"></a>
<div class="content overflow-hidden text-medium"><p><?echo $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"];?></p></div>
<?endif;?>
</div>
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

На 1С-Битрикс. Буду благодарен!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что в цикл foreach обернут элемент `.row`, то есть `.row` в вашем случае будет выводиться для каждого элемента `$arResult["ITEMS"]` (поэтому на текущий момент элементы выводятся не в строку). Поскольку для каждого элемента должен выводиться `.col-md-6`, цикл должен выглядеть так:

```
<? if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die(); ?>

<div class="row">
    <? foreach ($arResult["ITEMS"] as $arItem): ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb20 mb50-md">
            <div class="h4"><a href="<?= $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>"><?= $arItem["NAME"] ?></a></div>
            <? if ($arParams["DISPLAY_PICTURE"] != "N" && is_array($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"])): ?>
                <a href="<?= $arItem["DETAIL_PAGE_URL"] ?>" 
                   class="float-md-left mr30-md w140-md mb20 d-block"
                   rel="nofollow">
                    <img class="full-max" 
                         src="<?= $arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"] ?>"
                         alt="<?= $arItem["NAME"] ?>" 
                         title="<?= $arItem["NAME"] ?>"
                    ></a>
                <div class="content overflow-hidden text-medium">
                    <p><? echo $arItem["PREVIEW_TEXT"]; ?></p>
                </div>
            <? endif; ?>
        </div>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло. Огромное спасибо. У меня такая же проблема только в другом компоненте, здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032062/Нужна-помощь-перепробывал-многое-Отображение-в-строку-и-продолжение