# Нужна помощь, перепробывал многое. Отображение в строку и продолжение!

Tags: битрикс

Нужна помощь, перепробывал многое. Отображение в строку.

[image: НУЖНО ТАК]
[image: СЕЙЧАС ТАК]

ШАБЛОН КОМПОНЕНТА

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>

<?
 $TOP_DEPTH = $arResult["SECTION"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 $CURRENT_DEPTH = $TOP_DEPTH;

 foreach($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $arSection)
 {
  $this->AddEditAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_EDIT"));
  $this->AddDeleteAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCSL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
  if($CURRENT_DEPTH < $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH),"<ul>";
  }
  elseif($CURRENT_DEPTH == $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "</li>";
  }
  else
  {
   while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
   {
    echo "</li>";
    echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"</ul>","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-1);
    $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
   }
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"</li>";
  }

  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH);
  ?>
  

<ul id="items-list" class="items-tile" >
<li id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arSection['ID']);?>" class="before after ease-out"><div class="pd20">
<div class="h4"><a href="<?=$arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]?>"><?=$arSection["NAME"]?></a></div>
<div class="content text-small mb10"><?=$arSection["DESCRIPTION"]?></div>
</div></li>
</ul>

<?

  $CURRENT_DEPTH = $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 }

 while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $TOP_DEPTH)
 {
  echo "</li>";
  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"</ul>","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-2);
  $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: В настройках компонента можно выбрать вид "плитка". Либо если ваша версия компонента такое не поддерживает, то что вы попробовали сделать для того чтобы изменить вид? В гугле полно статей по созданию плиточного вида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.

Получилось вот так!

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?>


<ul id="items-list" class="items-tile" >
<?
 $TOP_DEPTH = $arResult["SECTION"]["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 $CURRENT_DEPTH = $TOP_DEPTH;

 foreach($arResult["SECTIONS"] as $arSection)
 {
  $this->AddEditAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_EDIT"));
  $this->AddDeleteAction($arSection['ID'], $arSection['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arSection["IBLOCK_ID"], "SECTION_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BCSL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
  if($CURRENT_DEPTH < $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH),"";
  }
  elseif($CURRENT_DEPTH == $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
  {
   echo "";
  }
  else
  {
   while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"])
   {
    echo "";
    echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-1);
    $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
   }
   echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"";
  }

  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"]-$TOP_DEPTH);
  ?>
  


<li id="<?=$this->GetEditAreaId($arSection['ID']);?>" class="before after ease-out"><div class="pd20">
<div class="h4"><a href="<?=$arSection["SECTION_PAGE_URL"]?>"><?=$arSection["NAME"]?></a></div>
<div class="content text-small mb10"><?=$arSection["DESCRIPTION"]?></div>
</div></li>


<?

  $CURRENT_DEPTH = $arSection["DEPTH_LEVEL"];
 }

 while($CURRENT_DEPTH > $TOP_DEPTH)
 {
  echo "";
  echo "\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH),"","\n",str_repeat("\t", $CURRENT_DEPTH-$TOP_DEPTH-2);
  $CURRENT_DEPTH--;
 }
 ?>
```